# Python Web Scraper Using Requests - Not Redirecting Like It Should

Tags: python, scripting, web-scraping

So I was bored, and I decided to do some web scraping just for fun and work on my programming skills. I tried to scrape a more "difficult" site such as http://www.aa.com (American Airlines). I say difficult because it has a redirect url after you search for a flight.

My current code is:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    req = self.session.get("http://www.aa.com/homePage.do", allow_redirects=True)
    cookies = req.cookies
    params = {
    "originAirport": "JFK",
    "destinationAirport": "LAX",
    "flightParams.flightDateParams.travelMonth": "3",
    "flightParams.flightDateParams.travelDay": "11",
    "flightParams.flightDateParams.searchTime": "120001",
    "carrierPreference": "F",
    "flightSearch": "revenue",
    "tripType": "oneWay",
    "fromSearchPage": "true",
    "searchCategory": "false",
    "adultPassengerCount": "1",
    "searchType": "matrix"
    }

req = self.session.post("http://www.aa.com/reservation/tripSearchSubmit.do;jsessionid=" + str(cookies.get("JSESSIONID")), data=params, allow_redirects=True);
            soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
            print(str(req.history) + "\n" + str(req.url))

            print(soup.prettify())
```

But this isn't working correctly. It just takes me to the loading page but doesn't redirect to the flight fares page (the req.history array is empty). Anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` will automatically handle HTTP redirects, but not necessarily other kinds of redirects. In particular, the page you linked does a Javascript redirect (and potentially other Javascript behavior). Remember, `requests` is a library which makes HTTP requests, but it does not implement the full range of behaviors of a proper web browser (most notably Javascript).

You can special case around this by studying the page contents and implementing behavior which mirrors the redirect.

To handle this correctly in the general case, you need something with more awareness of how web browsers work. Most commonly, this would be an actual web browser driven by an automation library, for example Selenium: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium